# How can I continue my count from the correct spot once I load the saved count?

Tags: objective-c

I am very new at coding, and am practicing and am making a simple tally/counter app. I am trying to save and load the number so users can continue where they left off once they close the app.

The save and load buttons work really well actually...except once I load the saved number, and I press the +1 or -1 buttons, it starts from 0 as if it were a fresh load of the app without the saved data.

How can I make it so when the user loads the saved number, the +1 and -1 buttons can read that loaded number?

This is my +1 button..haven't changed it:

```
-(IBAction)Up:(id)sender; {


    Number = Number + 1;
    Count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Number];

}
```

These are my save and load buttons:

```
-(IBAction)save {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:@(self.number) forKey:@"number"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
-(IBAction)load {


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:@(self.number) forKey:@"number"];
    self.number = [[defaults objectForKey:@"number"] integerValue];

}
```

Here is the extra part at the bottom :

```
    - (void)setNumber:(NSInteger)number {
        _number = number;
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _number];
        // this part is giving a warning says "writable atomic property 'number' cannot
        // pair a synthesized getter with a user defined setter
    }
```

And finally here is my .h

```
int Number;


@interface ViewController : UIViewController


{
    IBOutlet UISwitch *theswitch;
    IBOutlet UILabel *count;


}

-(IBAction)Up:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Down:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Reset:(id)sender;

-(IBAction) save;
-(IBAction) load;

@property NSInteger number;

@property (assign) UILabel *label;


@end
```

I feel like this is a simple fix.. help?!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, start variable names with a lower case letter.

Is `Count` a `UILabel`? You are setting the text, but you are never updating the actual `Number`. So instead of saving an `NSString`, save an `NSNumber` instead:

```
[defaults setObject:@(self.number) forKey:@"number"]
```

Make `Number` a property:

```
@property NSInteger number;
```

You can then write a custom setter for your number property

```
- (void)setNumber:(NSInteger)number {
    _number = number;
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%l", _number];
    // your label should also be a propery
}
```

When you load, just set the number like that:

```
self.number = [[defaults objectForKey:@"number"] integerValue]
```

#### about your updated question:

The warning you see is because your property is `atomic` and the custom setter you are implementing is nonatomic. The property declaration should actually be `@property (nonatomic) NSInteger number;` (what this means is outside the scope of this question).

You are never actually using that property. Get rid of `int Number;` and replace all occurrences of `Number` with `self.number`. That way, you are using the custom setter for your property.

The method for the button should look like this:

```
-(IBAction)up:(id)sender; {
    self.number = self.number+1;
}
```

Updating the label is handled in the setter for `number`.

Also remove `[defaults setObject:@(self.number) forKey:@"number"];` from `load`:

```
-(IBAction)load {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.number = [[defaults objectForKey:@"number"] integerValue];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Sebastian. However, I think my rookie mistakes are getting in the way still. Can you look at my updated question above and try to see what is the matter? Thank you so much.

Comment: Your up and down methods need to be updated to refer to the property that you've added, instead of continuing to refer to the `Number` variable.  Change `Number` to `self.number` and `Count.text` to `self.label.text`.

Comment: @AlexTrimpe: I've updated my answer. There are many things wrong in your code, I think you should read a good book on Objective-C/UIKit to get the basics right.